# React Enzyme get all classes even if passed by other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

Say I have

```
const BaseComponent = (props) => {
    const classNames = ['base-component', props.className];
    return (
        <div className={classNames.join(' ')}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
};

const SomeComponent = () => {
    return (
        <BaseComponent
            className="foo-bar"
        >
            Hello
        </BaseComponent>
    );
}
```

The rendered dom here would be `<div class="base-component foo-bar">Hello</div>`

Now, if I shallow mount `SomeComponent` and test the classes, only `foo-bar` is available:

```
const dom = shallow(<SomeComponent/>);
console.log(dom.hassClass('base-component')); // comes out as false
```

I understand that only `foo-bar` was passed as the class to `SomeComponent` but how do I validate all other classes here too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you use the `.prop` API.

```
expect(dom.find('div').prop('className'))
  .to.be.equal('base-component foo-bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

`shallow()` does only render the top level component which does not include your other class. You can use [dive()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md) to let it render the one component one level deeper. `dive()` renders the only one non-DOM child of the wrapper it was called on.

```
const dom = shallow(<SomeComponent/>);
console.log(dom.dive().hasClass('base-component')); // now comes out as true
```

If you want inspect the whole DOM you will have to use `render()` instead of `shallow()`.

Also not that a call to `html()` on a `ShallowWrapper` will always return the markup of a full render no matter if it was a shallow render or not.